# How to send mailmessage.to so recipients don't see each others email

Tags: c#

Is it possible to send an email from the `MailMessage` class to multiple recipients without them all being included in the same email?

Currently I have the email sending, but It sends one email to everyone in a column in a SQL table.

Below is what I have:

```
var announcements = db.Subscriptions.Where(x => x.Subscribed1 == true)
                                    .Select(x => x.Username);

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("update@company.com", "Update");

foreach (var address in announcements)
{
    if (article.ContentId == 1)
    {
        message.To.Add(address + "@delta.edu");
    }
}

message.Subject = "Populate";
message.Body = "Headline data";

client.Send(message);
```

Comment: you can use `MailMessage.bcc` which as per mail default, only the person see the mail and can't see other's recipient

Comment: Correct... "BCC" stands for BLIND Carbon Copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any email in general, you just use the BCC field to do this. "BCC" means ["blind carbon copy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy). The email will be sent to those recipients without any other recipients seeing their email address.

So in your case, just use the [`Bcc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc?view=netframework-4.8) property instead of `To`:

```
message.Bcc.Add(address + "@delta.edu");
```

Comment: I was just complaining to my friend about this and she texted me the exact same thing. I don't know why this didn't occur to me. Anyways, thank you!!